# Necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

> I need a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic over integers.

I got this on wikipedia [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#)

If $\alpha$ is an irrational number which is the root of an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n>0$ with integer coefficients, then there exists a real number $A>0$ such that, for all integers $p$, $q$, with $q>0$, $$\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{A}{q^n}$$

Is the above condition necessary and sufficient both?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you'd use that...you don't know what $n$ is, a priori.  Such inequalities are often used to prove transcendence, of course.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. But then is it not a necessary and sufficient condition? If not then what is a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic?

Comment: The definition of algebraic number provides a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic.

Comment: What's wrong with the definition?  There certainly are no simple deterministic tests one can reliably apply, sadly.

Comment: @Gonçalo So the theorem which I have given reference of wikipedia is a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic?

Comment: The definition is that it must be a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients.  That is both necessary and sufficient (well, it's a definition after all).

Comment: @lulu But the theorem which I wrote in my question is a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic?

Comment: Well, at a minimum you need to add a quantifier for $n$.  But, I'm not sure that the existence of such an $n$ implies alegraicity of that degree (I expect that is known, just not by me).  In any case, as I say, this isn't a very practical tool for demonstrating that a given number is algebraic.

Comment: Following from irrationality measure described on the page you linked, if you take $n>2$, then $\alpha$ does not have to be algebraic, so the condition is not sufficient. I’m not sure about “for all integers”, but “for infinitely many integers” would be a necessary condition for $n>2$, I’m not sure about $n=2$

Comment: @DavidChew Thanks. Can you please give a necessary and sufficient condition for a number to be algebraic apart from its definition?

Comment: What you got on Wikipedia is that an algebraic irrationality of degree $n$ has _irrationality measure_ at most $n$. This is ***not*** what Wikipedia says on the subject. In fact, a much stronger statement is true: any algebraic irrationality of any degree has irrationality measure exactly equal to $2$. This condition is necessary, but not sufficient. There are many numbers that have irrationality measure of 2, but are not  algebraic.